# I encountered a gconf2 error while installing some packages, what should I do?

Tags: dpkg, gconf

I got this error when installing some software:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up gconf2 (3.2.0-0ubuntu1) ...
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/usr/share/gconf/schemas/compiz-wobbly.schemas"
Failed to open `/usr/share/gconf/schemas/compiz-wobbly.schemas': No such file or directory
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/usr/share/gconf/schemas/gwd.schemas"
Failed to open `/usr/share/gconf/schemas/gwd.schemas': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing gconf2 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mutter-common:
 mutter-common depends on gconf2 (>= 2.28.1-2); however:
  Package gconf2 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing mutter-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmutter0:
 libmutter0 depends on mutter-common (>= 3.2); however:
  Package mutter-common is not configured yet.
 libmutter0 depends on mutter-common (<< 3.3); however:
  Package mutter-common is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libmutter0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gir1.2-mutter-3.0:
 gir1.2-mutter-3.0 depends on libmutter0 (>= 3.1.92); however:
  Package libmutter0 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing gir1.2-mutter-3.0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnome-shell:
 gnome-shell depends on gir1.2-mutter-3.0; hNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                      No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                            owever:
  Package gir1.2-mutter-3.0 is not configured yet.
 gnome-shell depends on libmutter0 (>= 3.2.1); however:
  Package libmutter0 is not configured yet.
 gnome-shell depends on gconf2 (>= 2.28.1-2); however:
  Package gconf2 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing gnome-shell (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gconf2
 mutter-common
 libmutter0
 gir1.2-mutter-3.0
 gnome-shell
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Please update the question with the relevant part from `/var/log/apt/term.log`. This should contain the error message that triggered the error exit status.

Answer (score 16):

Just hit one command in the terminal to fix that problem:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

And the problem will be solved.

Comment: Fixed the problem like a charm

Answer (score 12):

In linux mint, I solved the problem via first:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

then:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Works. 
Man I had to use mint after 2 years with Arch and this error cropped up.
Mint was supposed to be the easiest of all..
Thanks

Answer (score 8):

It is saying

```
Package gconf2 is not configured yet.
```

Have you tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gconf2`?
If that doesn't work, try `sudo apt-get remove --purge gconf2 && sudo apt-get install gconf2`.

Comment: This solved the issue `sudo apt-get remove --purge gconf2`

Answer (score 1):

These two commands can fix some package-management issues:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! **;-)** Could you please elaborate your answer on the why and how this will help? As is stands, your answer is likely to be deleted for being unclear.

Answer (score -2):

It's I/O error! Your hard disk is failing. Use command `dmesg` and check if kernel log show a Input/Output error in the hard disk. Then check the File-System by running `fsck.ext4 /dev/sda1`, and reinstall the package that contain file:

```
apt-file search /usr/share/gconf/schemas/gwd.schemas
apt-file search /usr/share/gconf/schemas/compiz-wobbly.schemas 
apt-get install --reinstall $package1 $package2
```

PS: buy a new hard drive!

Comment: What are `$package1` and `$package2`? What does 'PD' stand for?

Comment: This isn't true and there is no evidence of a failing hard drive.