# Error were encountered while processing Postfix mailutils in ubuntu 18.04 VM on vmware workstation 10

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, postfix, error-handling

dpkg: error processing package mailutils (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a follow up error from a previous failure.
How can i fix this error in my ubuntu 18.04 vm?

Comment: i use sudo apt-get -f install, did not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Dependency problems, leaving unconfigured" for many packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/862327/dependency-problems-leaving-unconfigured-for-many-packages)