Failed upgrade from 22.04.4 LTS to 24.04.1 LTS with the error message "could not install gconf2"
Toady I tried upgrading my system from Jammy Jellyfish to Noble Numbat and the update failed forcing me to restore my system from a system image I created using Clonezilla. I have attached the images I took of both of the messages I received when trying to update my system. What should I do to fix this issue and upgrade my system?

I have also attached the full output of apt policy gconf2 and sudo apt update as requested.
    chase@chase-System-Product-Name:~$ apt policy gconf2
gconf2:
  Installed: 3.2.6-7ubuntu2
  Candidate: 3.2.6-7ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 3.2.6-7ubuntu2 500
        500 https://mirrors.wikimedia.org/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
chase@chase-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for chase: 
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [129 kB]
Get:2 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease [1,825 B]        
Hit:3 https://mirrors.wikimedia.org/ubuntu jammy InRelease                     
Get:4 https://mirrors.wikimedia.org/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [128 kB]    
Get:5 https://mirrors.wikimedia.org/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [129 kB]   
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe i386 Packages [626 kB]
Hit:7 https://mirrors.wikimedia.org/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease           
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 Packages [899 kB]
Get:9 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages [1,087 B]
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe Translation-en [175 kB]
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [19.2 kB]
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main i386 Packages [531 kB]
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages [1,769 kB]
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main Translation-en [291 kB]
Get:15 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu jammy-apps-security InRelease [7,553 B]
Get:16 https://mirrors.wikimedia.org/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages [1,987 kB]
Get:17 https://apt.syncthing.net syncthing InRelease [15.1 kB]                 
Get:18 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu jammy-apps-updates InRelease [7,456 B]
Get:19 https://mirrors.wikimedia.org/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe i386 Packages [730 kB]
Get:20 https://mirrors.wikimedia.org/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1,121 kB]
Get:21 https://mirrors.wikimedia.org/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe Translation-en [260 kB]
Get:22 https://mirrors.wikimedia.org/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [26.1 kB]
Get:23 https://mirrors.wikimedia.org/ubuntu jammy-security/universe i386 Packages [626 kB]
Get:24 https://mirrors.wikimedia.org/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 Packages [899 kB]
Get:25 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu jammy-infra-security InRelease [7,450 B]
Get:26 https://mirrors.wikimedia.org/ubuntu jammy-security/universe Translation-en [175 kB]
Get:27 https://mirrors.wikimedia.org/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [19.2 kB]
Get:28 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu jammy-infra-updates InRelease [7,449 B]
Get:29 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu jammy-apps-security/main amd64 Packages [92.3 kB]
Get:30 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu jammy-apps-security/main i386 Packages [64.3 kB]
Hit:31 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/appimagelauncher-team/stable/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:32 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/openrazer/stable/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:33 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/polychromatic/stable/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Fetched 10.7 MB in 1s (8,610 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
12 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
chase@chase-System-Product-Name:~$


+1 for taking a clone first. Please edit your question and show the full output of apt policy gconf2 and sudo apt update

I can attach the output of the clone. After the update failed it was unresponsive until I restored it.

I suggest doing the 12 updates, then removing the launchpad ppas and any programs installed from them, then retrying it. I would say back up your data but you already did.

Okay, so would I run apt list upgrade to do that? And how would I remove the launchpad ppas? Sorry if it's a stupid question, I still don't remember all of the basic commands by heart.

sudo apt upgrade should do the upgrades. This answer describes how to use ppa-purge https://askubuntu.com/a/313/243321

Thanks, I'll give it a shot later this week and post an update.

I didn't see anything wrong with gconf2 so that is still a mystery.

Interesting, I wonder if I should wait for some updates or just go for it after removing the ppa's.

Would some of the suggestions in this thread help in your opinion? https://askubuntu.com/questions/77475/i-encountered-a-gconf2-error-while-installing-some-packages-what-should-i-do

The second attempt also failed after the suggested system prep. I submitted a bug report on launchpad to see what happens https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/2080541

By reviewing the bug notes it looks like the update failed due to a 127 error caused by a permission error, broken symlinks, and the infamous gconf2 error. I found the error message in the main log. There's more logs on launchpad if they might help. Do you have any ideas on what I should try next? @OrganicMarble
24-09-12 11:02:59,017 ERROR got an error from dpkg for pkg: 'gconf2': 'dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed' 2024-09-12 11:02:59,018 DEBUG running apport_pkgfailure() gconf2: dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed

So far it appears that this caused by an internal ordering bug in dpkg according to the bug report I submitted with Ubuntu. You can follow the bug report for new information.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/2080541
On a separate but related note; i was able to successfully "upgrade" by system by performing a clean install of Noble Numbat and using Aptik to transfer my settings, programs, ect.
